# Swift array empty on return

Tags: arrays, swift, alamofire

I have the following function (address and headers removed):

```
    func getChannelEPG(id: String) -> [GlossGuide]{

   var guide = [GlossGuide]()

    Alamofire
        .request(.POST, "http://link.to.api")
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let JSON2 = response.result.value {
                if let responseguide = JSON2["g"]!![id] as! [AnyObject]? {
                    for item in responseguide{
                        if let thisitem = GlossGuide(json: item as! JSON){
                            guide.append(thisitem)
                        }
                    }
                }
                print("Elements1: \(guide.count)")
            }
            print("Elements2: \(guide.count)")
    }
    print("Elements3: \(guide.count)")
    return guide
}
```

The three prints return the following:

Elements3: 0

Elements1: 14

Elements2: 14

Why is elements 3 (the one I want to return) 0, when there's clearly 14 elements in the array before that. Is the return somehow called before my alamofire request?

Comment: I think there's a reason why `Elements3` prints first :)

Comment: It's because the call is asynchronous.

Comment: I'm an idiot - thanks guys

Comment: You should read the "Response Handling" part in the Alamofire README: *"Networking in Alamofire is done asynchronously..."* and the top-linked [alamofire] Q&A's here on SO. This has been asked repeatedly.